# Ionic 4 Cordova Payment with Stripe and SCA

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, stripe-payments, ionic4

With the SCA (https://stripe.com/docs/strong-customer-authentication),
I have to update my payment routine that was using the Charge API : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/charges-api

From the documentation, i understood that my options are Payment intent : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents
and Setup Intent : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse

In order to communicate between my front End and my Backend, I use stripe.js Element.
The problem is that, in order to reach the PaymentIntent API, i need https, and Cordova is not https but only http from what i understood as specified in the Stripe documentation :

> A Stripe Element contains an iframe that securely sends the payment information to Stripe over an HTTPS connection. The checkout page address must also start with https:// rather than http:// for your integration to work.

You can test your integration without using HTTPS. Enable it when you’re ready to accept live payments.

I would like to know how i could handle the Stripe PaymentIntent API with stripe.js Element on my Ionic Cordova application.
If anyone got an idea it would be an amazing help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [switch to using Payment Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration-synchronous) here.  Those API calls have to be made server-side, and your client-side Elements/Javascript calls can remain nearly same.

Comment: The thing is that the client need to get a secret intent, and to get this you need to be calling from an https source (cordova applications are only in http). Or am I missing something ?

Comment: hi @Aion did you solved this issue? I'm currently facing same. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: You must not make API calls that require a Secret Key from any client - you'll need to have some server-side code that does this on your behalf like in https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder